# Why Comparable and Comparator are consumers in PECS wildcard types in Java

Tags: java, generics, super, pecs

In Effective Java, in the item "Use bounded wildcards to increase API flexibility", when talking about the usage of PECS (producer-extends, consumer-super), the author mentioned that:

> Comparables are always consumers, so you should generally use Comparable<? super T> in preference to Comparable. The same is true of comparators; therefore, you should generally use Comparator<? super T> in preference to Comparator.

It is not clear to me why Comparables and Comparators are considered consumers.

In one of the topic discussing PECS, [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super), the consumer is usually referring to a Collection as a parameter for some generic method.

While here Comparable is just an interface.

Can anyone share some insights? Thanks!

Comment: They are consumers because the generic methods (`compareTo(T)` for `Comparable<T>` and `compare(T, T)` for `Comparator<T>`) take in (i.e. **consume**) `T`'s. For the collections, it depens whether your store `T`s in the collection (i.e. the `Collection` **consumes** `T`s) or retrieving `T`s from the collection (i.e. the `Collection` **produces** `T`s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A nice analogy can be drawn to the interfaces [`Consumer<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Consumer.html) and [`Supplier<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Supplier.html) (with `Supplier` being analogous to Producer). A `Consumer<T>` is a function that takes in a `T`, while a `Supplier<T>` is a function that returns a `T`. Notice that we are talking about method signatures and return type, we say nothing about the semantics of the method. This is a core property of PECS: it is independent of the semantics and can be determined solely on the signature and return type of the methods used.

Looking at [`Comparable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) and [`Comparator<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html), we find that both have methods (`int compareTo(T)` and `int compare(T, T)`) that take in, i.e. **consume**, `T`'s.

For the collections, we have to look on how we use the collection, i.e. if we are using producer- or consumer-methods:

- If we retrieve data from the collection (`T get(int)`, iterator, ...), the list **produces** values for us and we use `? extends T`.
- If we use the collection to store data, (i.e. we call `add(T)`, `addAll(Collection<T>)`, `contains(T)`, ...), we call consuming methods, thus the method is a **consumer** of our data and we use `? super T`.
- If we use a collection to both store and retrieve values, the collection acts as a **consumer and producer** at the same time, thus we have to use the precise `T`, neither using `... extends ...` nor `... super ...`.

Answer (score 3):

> „*…It is not clear to me why Comparables and Comparators are considered consumers.*…“

Anytime a method member of a generic class *`C<T>`*, *takes in* (i.e. „*consumes*“) an argument that is of type *`T`*, then that method is a *consumer of `T`s*.

So [*`Comparator<T>.compareTo(T o)`*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) is said to be a „*consumer*“ of the *`o`* object of the type represented by the type variable *`T`*.

Answer (score 3):

When we say "`Comparable` is a consumer", we actually mean "the method of the interface is a consumer". This is an answer to your doubt that "`Comparable` is just an interface."

See its signature: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)

```
int compareTo​(T o)
```

It consumes the generic `T`, it does not produce any generic object.